# How to pluralize day, week, and month words based on quantity in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, format

After a very long time of not coding and still being relatively new to php I created the following code block to calculate the age of dogs and puppies. During different life stages age is measured differently, just days, weeks and days, months and weeks, and finally in years and months.

I currently have two issues that need to be addressed in the following code.

1. dependent on the output of the age the result may be "2 years 1 Months" I need the code to be smart enough to change the output to "2 Years 1 Month" in this case month is singular no 's'. I need to do the same for Years, Months, Weeks, and Days. I know this could be done with a considerable amount of code bloat, but I am sure there is a clean way to do it.
2. still can't figure out how to check if the date passed into the function is in the past or future (such as a litter of puppies do in 2 weeks) so that the code can be more universal

I'm just an old dog who has been coding since the days when computer memory was measured in kb and you were a 'Senior Programmer' if you could navigate and program for ISAM data sets.

```
function CalcAgeDOB($DOBdate)
{
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
    $datetime1 = date_create($DOBdate);
    $datetime2 = date_create();
    $DifferenceFormatDays = "%a";

    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

    $TotalDays = (($interval->format($DifferenceFormatDays)));

    Switch ($TotalDays) {
        case ($TotalDays < 0):
            $ReturnText = "We are still waiting on arrival";
            break;
        case ($TotalDays == 0):
            $ReturnText = "We were born today";
            break;
        case (($TotalDays >= 1) and ($TotalDays < 31)):
            $ReturnText = $interval->format("%a Days");
            break;
        case (($TotalDays > 30) and ($TotalDays < 91)):
            $WholeWeeks = (int)(($TotalDays) / 7);
            $RemainDays = $TotalDays % 7;
            $ReturnText = "$WholeWeeks Weeks $RemainDays Days";
            break;
        case (($TotalDays > 90) and ($TotalDays < 366)):
            $MonthDays = $interval->format('%m,%d');
            $MonthDaysArray = explode(",", $MonthDays);
            $WholeMonths = $MonthDaysArray[0];
            $WholeWeeks = (int)($MonthDaysArray[1] / 7);
            $ReturnText = "$WholeMonths Months $WholeWeeks Weeks";
            break;
        case ($TotalDays > 365):
            $ReturnText = $interval->format('%y Years %m Months');
            break;
        default:
            $ReturnText = "Error";
            break;
    }

    return $ReturnText;    
}

echo CalcAgeDOB("02/08/2017");
```

----------------Edit 10/06/2017 -------------------------

Updated code block after implementing changes from  @Cy-Rossignol this took care of question 1. I still need to sort out if the date passed into the function is in the past or future. Plural function was also updated from suggestion to return empty string when passing a $quantity of zero. Converted control structure from switch to if /elseif per recommendations.

```
<?php

function pluralize($quantity, $singular, $plural, $format = '%d %s') 
{
    if (empty($quantity)) {
        return sprintf(""); 
    }

    if ($quantity === 1) {
        return sprintf($format, $quantity, $singular); 
    }

    return sprintf($format, $quantity, $plural); 
}

function CalcAgeDOB($DOBdate)
{
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
    $datetime1 = date_create($DOBdate);
    $datetime2 = date_create();
    $DifferenceFormatDays = "%a";

    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

    $TotalDays = ((int)($interval->format($DifferenceFormatDays)));

    if ($TotalDays < 0) {
            $ReturnText = "We are still waiting on arrival";
    } elseif (empty($TotalDays)) {
            $ReturnText = "We were born today";
    } elseif (($TotalDays >= 1) and ($TotalDays < 31)) {
            $ReturnText = pluralize(($TotalDays % 7), 'Day', 'Days');
    } elseif  (($TotalDays > 30) and ($TotalDays < 91)) {
            $ReturnText = pluralize(((int)($TotalDays / 7)), 'Week', 'Weeks') . ' ' . pluralize(($TotalDays % 7), 'Day', 'Days');
    } elseif (($TotalDays > 90) and ($TotalDays < 366)) {
            $MonthDays = $interval->format('%m,%d');
            $MonthDaysArray = explode(",", $MonthDays);
            $WholeMonths =(int)($MonthDaysArray[0]);
            $WholeWeeks = (int)($MonthDaysArray[1] / 7);
            $ReturnText = pluralize($WholeMonths, 'Month', 'Months') . ' ' . pluralize($WholeWeeks, 'Week', 'Weeks');
    } elseif ($TotalDays > 365) {
            $YearsMonths = $interval->format('%y,%m');
            $YearsMonthsArray = explode(",", $YearsMonths);
            $WholeYears =  (int)($YearsMonthsArray[0]);
            $WholeMonths = (int)($YearsMonthsArray[1]);
            $ReturnText = pluralize($WholeYears, 'Year', 'Years') . ' ' . pluralize($WholeMonths, 'Month', 'Months');
    } else {
            $ReturnText = "Error";            
    }

    return $ReturnText;

}



echo CalcAgeDOB("7/3/2016")

?>
```

Comment: This unconventional `switch` structure won't work as expected when `$TotalDays` is `0` because `0` evaluates to `false`, but `($TotalDays == 0)` evaluates to `true`. `switch` statements are meant for controlling flow by comparing the possible values that a variable can *equal*, but we're comparing that value to a secondary value external to the `switch` logic in the expression for each `case` branch. It works, for the most part, thanks to the dynamic nature of PHP, but hides mistakes as a side-effect. Consider using `if...else` blocks instead.

Comment: See the [PHP docs for `switch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For English, we can write a simple function that chooses the appropriate form of a word based on a provided quantity:

```
function pluralize($quantity, $singular, $plural, $format = '%d %s') 
{
    if ($quantity === 1) {
        return sprintf($format, $quantity, $singular); 
    }

    return sprintf($format, $quantity, $plural); 
}
```

Here's some example usage:

```
pluralize(5, 'child', 'children');              // "5 children"
pluralize(1, 'foot', 'feet');                   // "1 foot"
pluralize(0, 'day', 'days');                    // "0 days"
pluralize(3, 'person', 'people', '%2$s: %1$d'); // "people: 3"
```

The last example shows a custom format as allowed by [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). Here's how we can use the function in the example from the question:

```
function CalcAgeDOB($DOBDate) 
{
    ...
    switch ($TotalDays) {
        ... 
        case (($TotalDays > 30) and ($TotalDays < 91)):
            $ReturnText = pluralize((int)($TotalDays / 7), 'Week', 'Weeks') 
                . ' ' . pluralize($TotalDays % 7, 'Day', 'Days'); 
            );
            break;
...
```

When working with dates, consider using the [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) library which wraps PHP's date and time functionality with a great, expressive API:

```
$dob = Carbon::parse('2017-10-01 00:00:00'); 

$dob->diffInDays(Carbon::now());    // "5"
Carbon::now()->diffForHumans($dob); // "5 days ago"
```

We can use this library in combination with our `pluralize()` function above.